# Instantiating objects for use in static accessors

Tags: php

**Background**

I have two classes, A and B, where A is a class which is full of static methods (Behat/Mink step definitions), but using logic methods from an instance of class B.

What I want is to have class A be able to use methods from an instance of B, A will have no constructor.

```
class A {
    // This class needs an instance of B, but A has no constructor

    const B_INSTANCE = new B(); //Surely not?
}

class B {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function methodForUseInClassA() {...}
}
```

**Nuance**

Right now, I have A extending B, but for unit testing purposes, instantiating B would be a better solution.

**Question**

How can I facilitate this? Is there some accepted best practice for this?

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: Why didn't use extends ?  http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: Have a method in `A` which creates a new instance of `B`, like `getB() { return new B(); }` sounds like the only option which doesn't use a constructor and doesn't rely on DI.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ - That would work, but I'd have to instantiate one for each method in A, right?

Answer (score 0):

Either try to extend `class A extends B {}`, then you'll have access to the methods of B. Or try this one:

```
class A {
    //This class needs an instance of B, but A has no constructor
    private static $instanceOfB = null;

    // singleton returns always the same object while script is running
    public static function getInstanceOfB() {
        if( self::$instanceOfB === null ) {
            self::$instanceOfB = new B();
        }

        return self::$instanceOfB;
    }

    // always returns a new instance
    public static function getNewInstanceOfB() {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function methodForUseInClassA() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

You can call it like this, but I think extending is the better option, except you just need some static helper methods.

```
$b = A::getInstanceOfB();
$b->methodForUseInClassA();
```

Comment: Extending was my first thought as well, but do you think it makes sense for a class to extend some class X which basically just provides logic methods?

Comment: I think a static "Helper" class is the better way to do that